# Naming a new folder path based on formula

Tags: python, os.path

I am trying to create new folders based on the date. How can I use the below code to add a date or specific string to a folder path to make the new file named as such?

```
MonthNum = pd.to_datetime('today').strftime('%m.')
MonthName = pd.to_datetime('today').month_name()
Year = pd.to_datetime('today').strftime(' %Y')
FolderName = (MonthNum+MonthName+Year)

    if not os.path.exists(r'C:\Users\Test\'+FolderName):
        os.makedirs(r'C:\Users\Test\'+FolderName)
```

Comment: Does it produces any error?

Comment: `FolderName = (MonthNum+MonthName+Year)` Looks like you're doing it already.  What is the problem?

Comment: What is pd? Some Pandas thing? The code as posted may result in "`IndentationError: unexpected indent`".

Comment: Adding the FolderName within the os.path.exists() creates an error. You have to either define the path separately and add FolderName to that definition or use the os.path.join function to join a path to FolderName.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# using datetime
dt = datetime.now()
folderName = f"{dt.month}-{dt.strftime('%B')}-{dt.year}"

# using pandas
dt = pd.to_datetime('today')
folderName = f"{dt.month}-{dt.month_name()}-{dt.year}"


abspath = os.getcwd() # current dir or wherever you want to create a it
folder = os.path.join(abspath, folderName)
if not os.path.exists(folder):
    os.makedirs(folder)
```

[image]

Comment: A code dump and a screen dump. [An explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76510272/edit) would be in  order. But *** *** *** *** *** ***[without](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131011)*** *** *** *** *** *** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written right now.

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and [do the right thing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76510272/edit) (it covers answers as well). Thanks in advance.